# Is this inequality $P(A \cap B) \geq P(A) \cdot P(B)$ provable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

$P(A \cap B) \geq P(A) \cdot P(B)$?

My approach:

We know $A \cap B \subseteq A, A\cap B\subseteq B \implies P(A\cap B) \leq P(A), P(A\cap B) \leq P(B)$.

As both $P(A\cap B)$ is fraction less than the 2 fractions $P(A),P(B)$, we get $P(A\cap B) \geq P(A) \cdot P(B)$.

(say $P(A\cap B)$ = 0.4, then $P(A), P(B)$ will be at least 0.4. Now i assume P(A), P(B) are at least 0.4. SO, $P(A\cap B)$ = 0.4 >= 0.4*0.4 = P(A).P(B))

But how to prove it mathematically?.

Comment: Assume you toss a coin. Let $A$ be the event of getting a head, and $B$ be the event of getting a tail. Does your inequality hold in this case?

Comment: The only existing bounds on $P(A\cap B)$ in terms of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are the ones coming from inclusion-exclusion principle and $A\cap B\subseteq A$, $A\cap B\subseteq B$. Id est: $$\max\{0, P(A)+P(B)-1\}\le P(A\cap B)\le \min\{P(A),P(B)\}$$ by which I mean that for all triplets of numbers $(x,y,z)\in[0,1]^3$ that satisfy those inequalities there are a probability space and two $A,B$ such that $P(A)=x$, $P(B)=y$ and $P(A\cap B)=z$. Thre is no general relation between $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: $A\cap B$ can be impossible

Comment: This is a case where trying some basic examples of sets $A$ and $B$ can help solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say

- $P(A \cap B) \le 1$
- $P(A \cap B) \le P(A)$
- $P(A \cap B) \le P(B)$
- $P(A \cap B) \ge 0$
- $P(A \cap B) \ge P(A)+P(B)-1$

but unless you have more information, such as independence of $A$ and $B$ being equivalent to $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, there are no other constraints on $P(A \cap B)$.

It is certainly possible to have $P(A \cap B) < P(A)P(B)$, for example when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events, as well as in other cases.  If you throw a fair die, the probability of an even number is $\frac12$ and of a prime number is also $\frac12$, while the probability of an even prime is $\frac16$.

Comment: thank you, understood now